# Vue. Execute JS inside template tag without rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to execute code inside  tag.

I have two arrays, one of dataset and another of structure of the repeater. Schema have inside each object a 'value' propertie, that is default value in case that dataset object doesn't contains any value.

```
schema:[
  { type: 'text', name:'name', value:'John'},
  { type: 'number', name:'age', value:'0' }
]

dataset: [
  { name: 'Peter', age: 18 },
  { name: 'Luca' },
  { name: 'Anna', age: 25 }
]
```

I'm trying to do a repeater that contains inputs inside of it, and fill de data with dataset.

The code below works fine, after the code I explain my issue.

```
<template>
    <div class="repeater-container">
        <div class="repeater-wrapper">
            <div 
                class="repeater-item"
                v-for="(repeaterData, i) in dataset"
            >
                <template
                    v-for="(input, y) in schema"
                    :key="name+(i+1)+'_instance'+(y+1)"
                >
                    {{ (dataset[i][input.name]) ? input.value = dataset[i][input.name] : '' }}

                    <Input
                        :input="input"
                    />
                </template>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have a loop that make that repeater render same items that dataset contains.
Inside this loop I have another loop that print each input that schema content.

But I'm trying to take dataset value, but if not have value, take the default value.

All that is working, but the line: {{ (dataset[i][input.name]) ? input.value = dataset[i][input.name] : '' }} is rendering the value.
I want to know how to execute the same logic but avoiding rendering the result of ternary condition.

Input Component is mine, that works fine. I don't share it because is irrelevant and is more code to read that can complicate the reading.

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: the idea is never to do that in the code, delegate processing to its proper place, that way, it will be easier to follow your code for code review or reading, to find bugs, and more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to have a computed property called processedItems that preprocesses the data and adds a displayValue property to each item. I ran in to a similar problem the other day.

Comment: That works for me. As you tell me, I build a computed function that merge and edit like I need the array and then I have the data as I need. Thank you so much :).